# Xcode scheme pre-action script only get triggered before the 1st test if run a sequence of tests

Tags: xcode, xctest

I created a minimum project to test pre-actions script. In our UI Test cases, I want to perform the script before each test run. But I found the prescript only run before the 1st test case.

It is proved by `say "Pre build scripts running."`. Could I know what is the reason?

Xcode 14.3.1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what it was designed to do: give you a chance to run something once before any tests run. It's completely external to the tests.

To run something before each test case, create an `XCTestCase` subclass that executes what you want in its set-up. Then for each of your test suites, subclass this. (If any test suite has its own set-up, it should call the `super` set-up first.)

Comment: Yeah, I think that is by design too. Because in some scenarios, we want to uninstall / reinstall app before each tests, and that is unable to achieved in XCTest script, aka setup() or teardown(). So I think may be we could use shell command to do it. Well I would leave those tests to QA for manual run.